# How do I do a paragraph ("p") tag in Arbre?

Tags: arbre

I can do a `div` tag like this:

```
2.1.0 :014 > Arbre::Context.new { div "foo" }
 => <div>foo</div>
```

And a `span` tag like this:

```
2.1.0 :017 > Arbre::Context.new { span "foo" }
 => <span>foo</span>
```

But this convention doesn't work for the `p` (paragraph) tag:

```
2.1.0 :020 > Arbre::Context.new { p "foo" }
"foo"
 =>
```

Obviously this doesn't work because `p` is already used in Ruby.

How do I do a paragraph tag in Arbre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Arbre, the paragraph function is `para`:

```
2.1.0 :021 > Arbre::Context.new { para "foo" }
 => <p>foo</p>
```

I was not able to find this in any docs.  I just got lucky.

Comment: This makes sense, wouldn't want to override [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p)